# почему не отображаются иконки

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from './Menu.css'

export default function Menu(props) {
    const cls = [
        'Menu',
        'fa'
    ];

    if (props.isOpen) {
        cls.push('fa-times')
        cls.push(classes.open)
    } else {
        cls.push('fa-bars')
    };

    return (
        <i
            className={cls.join(' ')}
            onClick={props.openMenu}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: не подключили может?

Comment: как подключить?

Comment: @AnaidaSaginova, импортировать

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `import classes from './Menu.css'` это `import './Menu.css'`

Comment: component импортировал

Comment: я знаю///////////

Comment: @Voprositel, навряд там иконки будут :)

Comment: fa fa-bars написано же

Comment: yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
  yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
  yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome

Comment: net ne bootstrap

Comment: ну вот и их надо импортировать в главном файле `index.js` или `App.js`

Comment: Подскажите, как  ??

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react - ниже есть пример импортов